# Got connection timeout with rusted-cypher after 60 seconds

Tags: neo4j, rust

For the first step of my master thesis I have to compare some databases. Currently I play around with Neo4J. The job is to insert millions of records into the database. Therefore I used Rust and [rusted-cypher](https://docs.rs/rusted_cypher/1.1.0/rusted_cypher/). I decided to use a transaction of 250000 create statements. But I got the following error exactly after 60 seconds:

`Hyper(Io(Os { code: 104, kind: ConnectionReset, message: "Connection reset by peer" }))`

First I thought Neo4J cuts the connection, so I raise the transaction timeouts in `neo4j.conf`:

```
dbms.transaction.timeout=300s
dbms.rest.transaction.idle_timeout=300s
dbms.lock.acquisition.timeout=300s
```

But the error continues to appear. I tested with a lower transaction size of only 1000 create statements, which worked.

I searched in the code of 'rusted-cypher' and 'hyper'. The only timeout I found is located in [hyper::client::Builder](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.9/hyper/client/struct.Builder.html#method.keep_alive_timeout) but it is actually 90 seconds not 60.

Why does the connection get reset after 60 seconds?

Comment: It's probably neo4j who crash, try to get the log. No [mcve], why so much upvote ?